# Get Length of split in java

Tags: java, split

There is a string and I split it by whitespace and I want to get the last one.

```
String test = "Hey Hi Hello"; // Defining "test" String
test = test.split(" ")[2]; // Now "test" is "Hello"
System.out.print(test); // prints Hello
```

I should do this to get the last word of "test" String. But I know the length of the string. What should I do if I **don't** know the length of the String? What should I write between `[ ]` to get the last word?

For example when I get a data from an web page and I don't now the value is what.

Comment: temp = test.split(" "); test = temp[temp.length - 1]; ?

Comment: that's a very inefficient way to do it. a better way would be `test = test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test.split` returns an array of `String`s. Just save it somewhere instead of using it immediately and check its `length`.

```
String test = "Hey Hi Hello";
String[] words = test.split(" ");
test = words[words.length - 1];
System.out.print(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] temp = test.split(" "); //this will split whole string into array using white space.
test = temp[temp.length-1]; //gets the element at the last index of temp array
```